# What is the area of $OEAF$ in $ABC$ triangle in the following diagram?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, area

[image]

> The area of $ABC$ and $OBC$ triangle is $120$ and $24$ respectively.
>   $BC=16$, $EF=8$. Find out the area of $OEAF$ quadrilateral.

**Source: Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2014 Junior Category.**

I can find the height of $ABC$ and $OBC$ from the give information. But I can't get the area of $AEOF$. Can anyone help me with a hint?

Comment: Is O some special point?

Comment: I don't think so. It is 3 unit high from the base as per my calculation.

Comment: Is $\angle AFE = \angle ACB$ and $\angle AEF = \angle ABC$ ?

Comment: @programmer there is no such information in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick check with GeoGebra shows that no definite answer is possible: there are several triangles satisfying the given data but with different quadrilateral area.

[image]

Comment: So, there is not enough information in the question?

Comment: Exactly: looks like they forgot to add some other info.